# menu launcher stopped working

Tags: unity, autohide

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with a working auto-hide launcher bar, i.e., the touch to the left of the screen revealed the menu.  It has stopped working perhaps the result of an automatic update.  I have tried setting the sensitivity to no avail. I have turned off the auto-hide feature so that I have access to the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to the new Nvidia 304.51 drivers, it's a known bug with no fix at the moment, the only way to get the panel behaviour back is to revert to the previous driver release version.

Answer (score 4):

There's a workaround for this problem posted by Doug McMahon here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1057000/comments/37

From the comment:

> To be a bit more verbose - for those looking for a tmp workaround till fixed - if no current `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` then create one with this in it
>
> ```
> Section "Device"
>   Identifier "NVIDIA GeForce"
>   Driver "nvidia"
>   Option "ConstrainCursor" "no"
> EndSection
> ```
>
> If there already is an xorg.conf with a device section then just add a line line in the section
>
> ```
> Option ConstrainCursor" "no"
> ```

Comment: I can confirm that this workaround fixes the issue for me. Thanks!